# Skip webbrowser control sharepoint authentication

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webbrowser-control, office365

I have authenticated S.P ClientContext. Is there any way that I can skip authentication of sharepoint online office 365 using webbrowser control by using SPClientContext.

```
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.AllowNavigation = true;
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
        wb.Navigate("https://URLofSPO/sites/testSol/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
```